# Understanding the Webview (html) code coming from the server

Tags: android, html, webview

I am using an Android app downloaded from **playstore** and wanted to know whether the app uses Webview.
So, I tried intercepting the network calls with the help of **Charles (proxy)** and I found out that page is actually a webview from coming from the server and has the following code.

```
<tmpl>
    <scrs>
        <scr si="10" sts="U" ver="18" sti="109777" mi="CT" dd="N1104_c90`N1104_c130`N1104_c140`N1104_c80`N1104_c91`N1104_c131`N1104_c141`N1104_c81`MNDPLBL10`MNDPLBL20`MNDPLBL30`MNPDYBT0`MNPDYBT0`MNPDYBT1`MNPDYBT2`MNPDNBT0`MNPDNBT1`MNPDNBT2`" mwj="encrypt" ty="screen" cev="2" ceva="1001" irp="1" cty="3">
            <gds ne="24">
                <gd gi="g8" sti="106411" ne="1" sv="1" ty="grid" sh="1" dkc="6">
                    <com ci="userid" sti="102803" ty="ti" val2="10useridval2" dk="MUSERID0`MUSERID1" val0="10useridval0" mk="MUSERID" cf="Interstate-Light" itx="User Name" vl="6" dkc="10" />
                </gd>
                <gd gi="showgrd" sti="108220" ne="1" sv="1" ty="grid" sh="1" dkc="6">
                    <com ci="showname" sti="101784" ty="ti" cf="Interstate-Light" n="1" td="2" dkc="10" />
                </gd>
                <gd gi="g26" sti="109372" ne="1" sv="1" ty="grid" sh="1" dkc="6">
                    <com ci="c40" sti="10141881" ty="im" iif="1" dkc="6" />
                </gd>
                <gd gi="usergd" sti="108277" ne="1" sv="1" ty="grid" sh="1" dkc="6">
                    <com ci="txterr" sti="107346" tx="Please enter  the username" ty="tb" dkc="2" />
                </gd>
                <gd gi="Default Navigation Bar" sti="99998" ne="1" sv="1" sh="1" cty="4" dkc="6">
                    <com ci="Option Menu" sti="100369" ac="mxapi_SYSEXT" ano="1" tx="Back" im="icon_back" mwo="1" ty="opm" is="1" lrsk="2`0`0`0`0`0`1" dbk="1" bbo="1`1`1`1`1`1`0" bb10a="1" wmo="1`1`1`0`0`0`0" bb10ao="1" jmeo="1`1`1`1`1`1`1" vr="1" dkc="9" isac="1" />
                </gd>
                <gd gi="pwdgrd" sti="109680" ne="1" sv="1" ty="grid" sh="1" dkc="6">
                    <com ci="passwd" sti="103121" ty="ti" val2="10passwdval2" dn="1" cev="1" val0="10passwdval0" cf="Interstate-Light" cty="2" itx="Password" dkc="10" />
                </gd>
                <gd gi="errgrd" sti="105083" ne="1" sv="1" ty="grid" sh="1" dkc="6">
                    <com ci="txterr1" sti="101080" tx="Please enter the password" ty="tb" dkc="2" />
                </gd>
                <gd gi="rememberme" sti="109608" ne="1" sv="1" ty="grid" sh="1" dkc="6">
                    <com ci="remember" sti="109356" tx="Remember My User ID" ty="chrd" dm="1" cs="1" ke="1" dkc="5" icla="1" />
                </gd>
                <gd gi="g25" sti="105126" ne="1" sv="1" ty="grid" sh="1" dkc="6">
                    <com ci="other" sti="109890" ac="10" tx="Login as another user" ty="bt" va="OTHERUSER" dkc="8" />
                </gd>
                <gd gi="spacegrd" sti="107931" ne="1" sv="1" ty="grid" sh="1" dkc="6">
                    <com ci="c44" sti="106724" ty="sp" />
                </gd>
```

I wanted to fetch the username and password which is there over Webview, when the user clicks on the **Sign On** button. For that I wanted to fetch the **id** so that I can use `document.getElementById()` to fetch the values entered by user of the widgets but I am unable to do so.

In the above code, I found out that there is no `script` tag, not even mentioned that when we click on Sign In button, which script should get executed.

I am curious to know that like when a button is clicked, I wanted to know how this code is working.

I am really not getting the meaning of what is `sti` `cti` `com` tags, etc.

Are they custom tags? Also what is the meaning of the number which is there over sti tags?

Is there any approach such that when user clicks on the **Sign In** button, I can fetch what the user has given as input?

Can someone please help me regarding the same?
Edit: Full source code can be found through this link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kG7ovPNjIjo3KrX1wSL1h8bSYwL6ixg_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: this is not html... xml maybe?  It's data for something else to use.

Comment: @pcalkins Thanks for your response.I think it's an html page. Because it is starting from html tag. I am sharing full source code through this link. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kG7ovPNjIjo3KrX1wSL1h8bSYwL6ixg_/view?usp=sharing.